# Buildship Gradle plugin Tasks Load hangs/gets stuck in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I've been using Gradle Buildship plugins in Eclipse around a year. Now Eclipse is getting hung up on the process of Loading tasks of all Gradle projects. In the past, this task usually took a few seconds at startup and I didn't think anything of it.

- If Gradle Tasks view wasn't in focus in the workspace this task wouldn't happen until it was opened.
- In workspaces that don't have the Gradle Tasks view in focus this doesn't start until I click on the Gradle Tasks view.
- I've looked in the workspace.metadata.log   - but I don't see anything that appears to be relevent to this issue.

Any help with how to start to debug this, or where else to look would be appreciated.  
*Also - has this happened to others?* I don't often hit an Eclipse or Gradle problem that hasn't been recently described in StackOverflow. The closest ones I've seen don't seem to apply - rather old, like 2016 or earlier, and the conditions seem to be "takes a long time" or describe an error message.

Other details

- Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22.0) updated from Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0)
- Gradle - using the Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0
  [image]

########### Helpful info #################
I found that I can at least stop the buildship task using the osgi console in Eclipse:[image: Eclipse tasks]
Next get a list of eclipse threads using command "threads" with no arguments. 
Use "threads stop 'taskname'"   note that the entire task name isn't printed by the threads command?! I got that later part of the name from the Progress window.
[image: OSGi Console Host Window]

Comment: This has rendered the Buildship Gradle Integration effectively unusable. Until I figure out how to get it working again I'll use a kludgey work-around I'll use gradle command-line.  :/

Comment: ? I'll ask again - Has anyone else had a similar problem? I noticed a few views but no feedback. And btw I've (re)learned that Gradle command-line is actually easy to use. I just hadn't needed it in so long since I started using the Buildship.  :)

Comment: Likely related? https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1128

Comment: After a week or so of just dealing with the symptom, the problem seems to have cleared up. Frankly I'm so glad it's working now but there was no information that I could take away from this. What (if any) update to Eclipse-or-Plugin-or-Windows may have contributed to fix this? It would be very useful to know, so I'm keeping this question open for now.  I'd rest easier if there was an answer as I depend on these tools!  It's an uncomfortable mystery for the moment :)  Thank you to all who looked into it! and Best regards Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you close "Gradle Tasks" view or just make it inactive by hiding its content behind some other view then Eclipse will not attempt to load gradle tasks at all. This view has little utility anyway and basically just wastes space.
2. At some point I had the same problem as you did, I fixed it by deleting and re-importing all projects to eclipse.